# Saving multiple gzip files using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, gzip

I am trying to increase the speed of the I/O in my app so I decided to store it using multiple threads. Files are structured in the hierarchy book/symbol/file, multiple threads saving multiple files in the same directory at the same time potentially. When I save all the files sequentially, there is no problem. However, when multiple thread kick in, sometimes the file is malformed and loading of it raises "IOException : invalid block". Any ideas why concurrency may screw things up in this case?

Code below:

```
    private void storeAppendingTimestamps(Series timeSeries) throws MetricPersistException {
        Metric metric = timeSeries.getMetric();
        Path outPutFile;
        try {
            outPutFile = generateOutputFilePath(metric);
            if (!Files.exists(outPutFile)) {
                createNewFile(outPutFile);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new PersistException("Cannot create output file for metric " + metric);
        }
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outPutFile.toFile(), true)), true)) {
            for (SeriesDataPoint dataPoint : timeSeries.getTimeSeriesPoints()) {
                writer.println(String.format("%d %s", dataPoint.getTimestamp().getMillis(), formatPlain(dataPoint.getValue())));
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MetricPersistException(String.format("IO Exception has occured while persisting metric %s: %s", metric, e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

And the code that splits the work:

```
private void persistTimeSeries(Collection<Series> allSeries, CompletionService<Void> executorService) throws MetricPersistException {
        final LoggingCounter counter = new LoggingCounter(logger, "metric series file", 10000);
        for (final MetricTimeSeries series : allSeries) {
            executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    persister.persistTimeSeries(series);
                    counter.increment();
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < allSeries.size(); i++) {
                Future<Void> future = executorService.take();
                future.get();
            }
            counter.finish();
        }
```

Comment: Can we see your code, pls ?

Comment: And the full error stack trace as well?

Comment: You know, concurrency in the hands of a novice tends to screw things up in virtually all cases, not just your case, right?

Comment: Also, check (benchmark) that it is really an advantage. With today computers your bottleneck will probably be I/O, and threading won't likely help there.

Comment: If you're IO-bound, adding threads will just make the problem worse.

Comment: I am afraid that your question will not be answered well enough without source code and the exception stack trace.

Comment: SPlitting to multiple threads helped in this case, 2- 2.5x faster with 16 threads than with 1

Comment: Since `Future.get()` is declared to throw two checked exceptions, and I don't see any exception-handling code in what you've pasted, I have to assume that you're not pasting your exact code.

Comment: Is your `persister` and `counter` thread safe? That can cause the issue

Comment: You don't need the `CompletionService` there. You can just store a list of `Future` and then iterate across the list calling the `get()`.  Also, FYI, you are not shutting down the `CompletionService` in the code you've provided.

Comment: Also, FYI, String.format is more expensive than "metric " + metric + " ...".

Comment: Any chance that the threads are writing to the same file by accident?  Can `generateOutputFilePath(...)` with a different series generate the same filename?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments guys! The files are absolutely unique, so there should be no race conditions... I am even more puzzled now, as I have generated some synthetic data just to test the persister, and it does not seem to fail there... I ran it a couple of times and it saved all the files without any issues... Puzzled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for performance, then you'll almost certainly get a bigger performance boost from introducing a `BufferedOutputStream` between your `GZIPOutputStram` and `FileOutputStream`.

And while you're at it, add an `OutputStreamWriter` with a correct encoding specification, so that people who aren't running on your particular machine will be able to properly interpret the file.

---

The one piece of clearly thread-unsafe code that I see is in `storeAppendingTimestamps()`: if you have several series that would map to the same output file, then you have race conditions where they both open and write to the same file (there's also a race condition on creating the file, but I'll assume that's an idempotent operation).

If it's likely that you could have multiple series that map to the same filename, then you need to have a thread-safe/race-safe guard. Something like a `ConcurrentHashMap` that's used to store the names of files that you're processing. And exit the task (with a warning) if you have a collision.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question so is more suited as a comment.

Comment: @Gray - perhaps. But I feel that it's more useful to address the base issue than a specific implementation. Especially when the OP has not provided complete information.

Comment: How did this fix your problem @Bober02?

Comment: Adding a Buffer at that level konda just feels faster. You could simply increase the size of the buffer in your gzip stream to be faster. It just feels faster because you delay the io operation and the BufferedOutputTream has a bigger default size than the GZipOutputStrem but adding just buffers makes it hard to know how much ram you actually use up and when it is actually writing and how much